# Code Line disappears after pressing Enter, Del, Backspace, etc. in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, binding, f#, editor

I have Visual Studio 2022 Community and I primarily use it to code in F#. The weird thing is: For `let` bindings, whenever I want to change something and I press Backspace, Del, Enter, etc. - whenever I try to type anything at all, the line completely disappears. Not that it is gone, when I close the file without saving and reopen, it is still there. I tried resetting settings, removing all extensions, reinstall, clean install. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: One would normally report this through Visual Studio. In the menu, select Help / Send Feedback / Report a Problem.

Comment: @Brent I am sure if you have a Professional or Enterprise licence, they offer would offer some professional support but the answer I got from the Visual Studio forum was: “Update your Windows, Visual Studio and make sure your Graphics drivers are up-to-date.”

What do you want me to do with such quality answer?!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was/is the F# CodeLense. This is highly experimental at the moment and better be disabled in the Visual Studio options.